# Using liip image filter outside of a twig

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I'm trying to use liip outside of a twig to convert several images (100+) to a smaller size in a cron job. I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The LiipImagineBundle integrates the standalone PHP "[Imagine library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)".

This library is already included in your project as dependency of the liipImageBundle so you can use standalone as example:

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();

$imagine->open('/path/to/image.jpg')
   ->save('/path/to/image.jpg', array('jpeg_quality' => 50)) // from 0 to 100
   ->save('/path/to/image.png', array('png_compression_level' => 9)); // from 0 to 9
```

Read [here](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/introduction.html#basic-usage) for the docs and more example.